# Split text from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this url

```
https://myapp.tezze-now.com/sp?id=form&table=user&sys_id=cb6688db0d79b5e9619&view=sp
```

I need to get text of table name from the url when page loads.
I tried this

```
location.href.split('&')[1]
```

It returns `"table=user"`. but I need  the table name alone as `user`.

How can I get this?

Comment: you can split the result using result.split('=');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

```js
 // location.href
let str = "https://myapp.tezze-now.com/sp?id=form&table=user&sys_id=cb6688db0d79b5e9619&view=sp"; 

console.log((new URL(str)).searchParams.get("table"));
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates. Close-vote them, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Split it once more:

```
location.href.split('&')[1].split('=')[1]
```

Or you could use [`Url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) class (no support in IE):

```js
var url = "https://myapp.tezze-now.com/sp?id=form&table=user&sys_id=cb6688db0d79b5e9619&view=sp"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url);
var table = url.searchParams.get("table");
console.log(table);
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates. Close-vote them, instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href.split('table=')[1].split('&')[0]
```

Don't assume the parameter order ;)